# Method Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Collection::addEagerConstraints does not exist

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm getting this error while I'm trying to fetch data from two tables.

this is my model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Stream extends Model
{
    public function subjects(){
        return $this->hasMany(Subject::class)->get();
    }
}
```

and this is my method in controller

```
public function viewStreamAndSubjects(){

        $data = Stream::with(['subjects'])->get()->all();
        dd($data);

    }
```

please tell me what I'm doing wrong here? Thank you.

Comment: Don't use `->get()` on the relation `subjects()`.

Comment: You also don't need `->get()->all()` on the model, `->get()` will suffice.